# Am I using Dynamic Programming? Matrix chain multiplication in c

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Halo I just write code to perform Matrix chain multiplication, which can be solved by Dynamic Programming
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication#A_Dynamic_Programming_Algorithm

Here is the code I wrote, which I think is simpler than the one provided by wikipedia. So I doubt am i doing dynamic programming or not?

and I can't figure out the time complexity of my program. Can someone help me to figure the time complexity of this program?

Here's my guess..
the for loop will run n times for each call? if mem is not used..
for each loop, it will then expand into two

if mem is used, it prevent recalculation... 
ahhh I can't figure it out, hope someone can help me :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <climits>

using namespace std;

int mem[10][10];
int row[10];
int col[10];
int m[10];

#define NUM 4

int DP(int c, int r){
    if(mem[c][r] != INT_MAX) return mem[c][r];
    if(c == r) return 0;
    int min_cost;
    for(int j=c; j<r; j++){
        min_cost = DP(c, j) + DP(j+1, r) + m[c-1]*m[j]*m[r];
        if(min_cost < mem[c][r])
            mem[c][r] = min_cost;
    }
    return mem[c][r];
}

int main(){
    for(int i=0; i< 10;i++){
        for(int j=0; j<10;j++){
            mem[i][j] = INT_MAX;
        }
    }
    int n = NUM; // MAX 4 matrix
    int a,b;
    for(int i=0; i< NUM+1; i++){
        cin >> a;
        m[i] = a;
    }

    cout << "Lowest Cost for matrix multiplicatoin " << DP(1,NUM);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memoized version of matrix chain multiplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079889/memoized-version-of-matrix-chain-multiplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you have used is called `memoization`. Most of the time, you may solve DP problems using memoization with little (or no) overhead.

The complexity of your implementation is just like the original DP solution: O(n^3) (Note: Every cell of `mem` array should be computed at least once, and each cell takes O(n) time to be computed. Further computation of a cell, does not involve any loop, since it would be a simple lookup.)

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization